# How do I address a column in a named cell range

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc, named-ranges

I have a named multi-column, labeled cell range. How do I access values from one of the columns?

Here's an example of the range:

[image: MyValue Cell range]

Now, Calc will help me get the entire cell-range:

[image: Getting Cell Range]

But what do I do to get just one column?

I tried `=sum(MyValues.Value)` and `=sum(MyValues["Value"])` but apparently that's not it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the quotes from your second formula and it should be OK:

```
=SUM(MyValues[Value])
```

[image]

The above assumed that you defined a database range.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I tried that actually, but I got n Err:507 in my case. If I just sum the whole range it works (because only one column has numbers) but I wanna learn how to do it properly.

Comment: @Zlatko Is the range defined as database range? Are the selected options the same as the image on the answer?

Comment: I'll have to check when I get to my computer.

Comment: You're correct, that was it. I did not define this as a database range, just a set of columns. I saw Joel Spolsky's video on Excel last week and wanted to try it, in his video it worked by simply defining it as a named range.

Comment: @Zlatko That's among the difference between Excel and Calc.

Answer (score -1):

This answer works on first input, but gets lost when spreadsheet is closed. When you save, close and re-open the spreadsheet, the myvalues[value] reference turns into $Sheet1.$B$2:$B$3. Any way of getting Libreoffice to keep the column label format?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1177847)